# How do you refer to all cells above the cell inside a match function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a list of courses in Google sheets to which items will be added daily by pasting them at the end of the current list. I then want to check if a course has already been added to the list before. If that is the case, the value of a certain column will get the value that the first occurrence of that course has. So I will be using =INDEX(MATCH... and the range in the match part will be all the cells in the column above the cell that is checked. The MATCH part of the formula is obvious if you drag or copy the formula downwards:

```
= MATCH(A2; A$1:A2; 0)
```

However I was experimenting with other ways of achieving this, namely

```
MATCH(A2; "A$1:A"&ROW()-1; 0)
```

(I also tried this one without the quotation marks) and

```
MATCH(A2; (ADDRESS(1;1;2)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1;1; 4)); 0)
```

Both of these don't work. I can't figure out why. (BTW, the semicolon is ok where I live). I get #N/A everywhere and the message that the value has not been found in the match evaluation.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Also: if I would get this to work, are there any advantages or disadvantages over copying the simple formula all the way downwards? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because second parameter of `MATCH` function requires range, but you in both cases pass the string. I don't know why you don't like the first option, but you may be able to use the `OFFSET` function.

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(A2; OFFSET($A$1;0;0;ROW()-1); 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not that I don't like the first option. But in another spreadsheet I had recently used ROW() in an INDIRECTfunction, so I was simply wondering whether an approach with ROW() would work as well and if there were any relevant differences between the different solutions. So my question was more about expanding my "toolbox" in Google sheets. But don't you think the error message "value not found" is misleading? Wouldn't a message like "second parameter of MATCH not a range" be more accurate?

Comment: @ChristofVandenEynde You can also use your ```MATCH``` functions if you include the second parameter in the ```INDIRECT``` function. i.e. ```MATCH(A2; INDIRECT("A$1:A"&ROW()-1); 0)```. But basically, the fewer functions you use, the faster the formula will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ArrayFormula approach so you only need a single formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(IF(MATCH(A2:A,A2:A,0)<>ROW(A2:A)-ROW()+1,A2:A,"N/A")))
```